# Why there is no instance found for this predicate? (Alloy)

Tags: alloy

I try to model a bug in O365 plugin loading mechanism, it's basically like the address book example in the book, the bug happens when you load one plugin and quit the plugin modal and then reopen it. The root cause is that when you load the plugin for the 1st time, outlook webpage load the plugin and recording the plugin's instance into a plain javascript object with the plugin's URL as its key, and when you close the modal, it clear all the instance but the keys remain in the object so the second time you open it, the loader get an empty object.

I wrote down the mechanism, but interestingly, I can't generate an instance for loading something into an empty DI, (actually, the same thing happens when I add the predicate into the address book example from the book, like addressBook1h.als). Can anyone help me to point out where did I do wrong? Thank you.

```
sig DI {
  plugins: Name one -> lone Kls
} {
  all disj n, n': Name |
    plugins[n] != plugins[n']
}

sig Name, Kls {}

fun lookup [d: DI, n: Name] : set Kls {
    n.(d.plugins)
}

pred load[d, d': DI, p: Name, k: Kls] {
  (no lookup[d, p]) => {
    d'.plugins = d.plugins + p->k
  }
  else
  d'.plugins = d.plugins
}

pred exit[d, d': DI] {
  d'.plugins.Kls = d.plugins.Kls
  and
  all n: Name |
   some d.plugins[n] => d'.plugins[n] = none
}

-- no instances
run {
  all disj d,d':DI|
    let n = Name |
      let k = Kls {
        no d.plugins
        and
        load[d, d', n, k]
      }
} for 3 but exactly 2 DI, exactly 1 Name, exactly 1 Kls
```

Comment: and if I start by saying that "I just want an empty DI" and click next button a few times, alloy can generate the situation that I want (evaluating 'load[DI$0, DI$1, Name, Kls]' gets a 'true')

Answer (score 0):

just remove 'exactly' and you will get the instances:

```
sig DI {


plugins: Name one -> lone Kls

} {



all disj n, n': Name |
    plugins[n] != plugins[n']
}

sig Name, Kls {}

fun lookup [d: DI, n: Name] : set Kls {
    n.(d.plugins)
}

pred load[d, d': DI, p: Name, k: Kls] {
  (no lookup[d, p]) => {
    d'.plugins = d.plugins + p->k
  }
  else
  d'.plugins = d.plugins
}

pred exit[d, d': DI] {
  d'.plugins.Kls = d.plugins.Kls
  and
  all n: Name |
   some d.plugins[n] => d'.plugins[n] = none
}

-- no instances
run {
  all disj d,d':DI|
    let n = Name |
      let k = Kls {
        no d.plugins
        and
        load[d, d', n, k]
      }
} for 3 but  2 DI ,  1 Name ,  1 Kls
```